# How to change text color of <li> item only using inline style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styling

I want to change the color of a list tags but I can only use inline style, any idea how to do it once, insted of writing inline style for each li tags. (No JS or Style tags)

Comment: apply the color to the `ul` or `ol`...

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers currently here use JS or the style tag.

The secret is that if you just want to change the text color, all you have to do is add that property to the parent element one time and it will apply to all of them.

This can be done either to the `ul` tag, or you can surround all of the `li` tags that you want to update with a `span` tag and change the inline style `color` property of that (this is usually how it's done).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CSS color property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color).

```html
<ul>
  <li style="color: red;">red li item</li>
  <li style="color: green;">green li item</li>
  <li style="color: blue;">blue li item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ul>
  <li style="color: red;">Item 01</li>
  <li style="color: green;">Item 02</li>
</ul>
```

You can also use hex color codes as well.

```
<ul>
  <li style="color: #ff0000;">Item 01</li>
  <li style="color: #00ff00;">Item 02</li>
</ul>
```

Without writing each line of `li` tags, you can wrap your `li` tags within `ul` tag and add style for `ul` tag like this.

```
<ul style="color: #ff0000;">
  <li>Item 01</li>
  <li>Item 02</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

in your style tag, select `li`

```
<style>
  li{
    color:red;
  }    
</style>
```